# 未ログイン状態で投稿を編集時のエラーメッセージを改善したい

Tags: バグ, メタ

未ログイン状態でスタック・オーバーフローMETAの[投稿を編集](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/3499/edit)するURLにジャンプすると403エラーが発生し、下記のテキストを返します。

```
キューの中に、提案されているが保留になっている編集があります。数分後にもう一度試してください。
```

末尾の添付画像のように`[クローズ済み]`のMETA質問には投稿編集を促すリンクが表示されますが、Google ChromeではUnicodeをShift-JISで読み込んで文字化けすることがあります。(Windows10およびAndroidにて投稿時点の最新版Chromeで確認)

新規ユーザはエラーメッセージを参考に数分ごとにリロードするかもしれません。
またChromeはユーザシェアが高い上に拡張機能を使わないと文字コード選択もできません。

コメントをいただきました通り、メタ特有の事象で意図しないエラーメッセージが発生しているのかもしれません。
既定の動作であるかをご確認いただけますでしょうか。
そしてエラーメッセージの文字化け対策は可能でしょうか。

[image: 投稿を編集する画面と遷移先の文字化け]

Comment: メインサイトでは再現しませんでした（Firefox, Google Chrome の最新版で試行）。

Comment: 情報ありがとうございます。メタタグを追加しました。

Comment: 未ログイン状態に限らず、信用度の低いユーザーが編集を行うとピアレビューに入るのですが、この挙動が正しく動いていないようです。"キューの中に" のメッセージも既に別の提案がある場合に表示されるべきメッセージなので、こちらも少しおかしいですね。

Comment: 関連候補: [Navigating to the edit mode of a not-exist page produces a strange error message](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/138879) / [Trying to edit a post when not logged in gives pending edit warning](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/399167)